# Is there a CDAP / Data Fusion plugin for transforming to Delta (Delta Lake) Format?

Tags: delta-lake, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'd like to use Data fusion on GCP as my ETL pipeline manager and store the raw data in GCS using the delta format. Has anyone done this, or does a plugin exist?

Answer (score 0):

Data Fusion has a plugin to read files/objects from a path in a Google Cloud Storage bucket and it does support the Parquet format. One approach can be to use cloud function to convert the delta to parquet and then use it in the data fusion pipeline.